# Generating a unique identifier list with multiple tables & criteria

Tags: excel

I'm not a coder, just someone who uses excel for basic estimating functions at work.  However I've found myself in need of a complex list or index system.

Background/Intent: (Skip below if doesn't matter.) In an apartment building construction they build buildings like opened books - mirror images of 2 bed 2 bath apartments, for example.  There is a standard "typical" unit and then the mirror image across the hall, the "reverse" unit.  The door swings are all opposite from one to the other.  My job is to figure out how to give each door a unique identifier code based on: Bldg No., Unit Type, Door No., Door Swing (left or right.)  The raw data tables are provided below.

I've attempted to clean this up as much as possible, but there are two steps (I think) to this process.

**Step 1:** 
The raw data table is on the left.  My output field is on the right.  I want to be able to select a drag down box, like data validation list, and select the building.  Then a formula **(which one?)** spits out a list of every unit type per building.  For example, Bldg 5 has 2 each of "A1 Typ." How do I get the formula to recognize that if there are 2 of them, to produce 2 separate lines for "A1 Typ."  And so on and so forth until all 41 occurences/units have been accounted for and labeled appropriately.  Some occur once, some multiple times, and some zero.
[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd1RB.png)

From there, **Step 2.**
I want to use this output field again to automate another sequence, this time pulling from a different table, see picture.  Now, depending on the unit type under the "type" column, I want it to expand each unit type showing each indivudual door number (1,2,3 etc through 12) and if it's an L (LH) or R (RH), and if there is more than one, to list out each occurence.   **(what formula?)**
Then the decriptor text that will pop up under "DOOR LABEL" column would just be a joining of several fields to give a unique identifier. **(suggestions?)**

[Step 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPAF0.png)

Easy right?  Is this too much for excel, or can this be done?
Thanks so much for considering helping me out!